# SequenceEqual linq group

Tags: c#, linq, equals

I write a simple program using c# 3.5 and linq .

i have class

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {

    }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
    public bool Read { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals((Product) obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(Product other)
    {
        return ObjectId == other.ObjectId && Read == other.Read;
    }

}
```

I am trying to compair list.

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>() 
{ 
    new Product { RoleId = 1, ObjectId = 2, Read = false }, 
    new Product { RoleId = 2, ObjectId = 1, Read = false }, 
    new Product { RoleId = 1, ObjectId = 1, Read = true } 
};

var groupedCustomerList = products.GroupBy(u => u.RoleId)
                                  .Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();

var firstGroup = groupedCustomerList.ElementAt(0);

List<Product> productsListSearch = new List<Product>() 
{ 
    new Product {ObjectId = 1, Read = true }, 
    new Product {ObjectId = 2, Read = false } 
};

var result= productsListSearch.SequenceEqual(firstGroup);
```

Why the result is incorrect ?
I need to sort the items?

Comment: can you post the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not sequence-equal because the objects come in different order. If you change `productsListSearch` like this

```
List<Product> productsListSearch = new List<Product>() 
{ 
    new Product {ObjectId = 2, Read = false } 
,   new Product {ObjectId = 1, Read = true }
};
```

`SequenceEqual` would return `True`.

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/vq2EJG).

Generally, you should not rely on the order of items in LINQ-generated groups, unless you set the order yourself:

```
var groupedCustomerList = products.GroupBy(u => u.RoleId)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(p => ...).ToList()).ToList();
```

Note: your `Product` class overrides `Equals` without overriding `GetHashCode`. This will be problematic if you decide to use `Product` in hash sets or as keys of hash-based dictionaries.

Comment: @LiranElisha I don't know how it shows up in debug, but it runs correctly (follow the link to ideone for a simple proof).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: _"you should not rely on the order of items in LINQ-generated groups"_ In Linq-to-Objects the order is well defined, it's the order of the input sequence. [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534304.aspx): _"The IGrouping<TKey, TElement> objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each IGrouping<TKey, TElement>. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order that the elements that produced them appear in source"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter Absolutely, the order is well defined. However, "natural order" (i.e. "the same as in the source") tends to be fragile, because small changes to the source, - say, replacing a list with a hash set, may change the natural order. It's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: if the source is "fragile", then not only the order is _fragile_ but the whole sequence. So either you know what happens or you need to create a collection with `ToList` to persist the state. My point was that it doesn't matter if an order was applied before a `GroupBy` or after. The result is the same(although sorting later can be more efficient).

Answer (score 1):

The lists are in different orders. Change second list to

```
    List<Product> productsListSearch = new List<Product>() 
{ 
    new Product {ObjectId = 2, Read = false },
    new Product {ObjectId = 1, Read = true } 
};
```

and the result will be true

SequenceEquals means the *sequence* has to be equal. You have the same elements in both collections but in a different sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your second data set is how you expect to see your main data once it is grouped and sorted.  In order for that to happen you need to change this line so that your grouped items will be sorted:

```
var groupedCustomerList = products.GroupBy (u => u.RoleId)
        .Select (u => u.OrderBy (x => x.ObjectId));
```

And this is a cleaner looking way to get the first element:

```
var firstGroup = groupedCustomerList.First ();
```